# xhtml and jQuery is there and easy way to append html?

Tags: jquery, append, xhtml

Login for an easy way to build html code in jQuery and appending to DOM without handling special html characters as below. appending yyyy doesn't work. Any easy way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


            $("div").append("xxxxx");
            $("div").append("<span>yyyyy</span>");
            $("div").append("&lt;span&gt;zzzzz&lt;&#x2F;span&gt;");


}); 



</script>


</head>
<body>
        <div>


        </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working with XML, the yyyyy is parsed character data, even though it's inside the script element. (The `text/html` HTML parser knows to switch to unparsed character data, but an XML parser doesn't)

So you need to tell it explicitly, using the CDATA delimeters `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` at the start and end of the script. So:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
    <![CDATA[

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").append("xxxxx");
        $("div").append("<span>yyyyy</span>");
        $("div").append("&lt;span&gt;zzzzz&lt;&#x2F;span&gt;");
    }); 

    ]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or, if you still want zzzzz to be added the way you've currently got it, add the CDATA delimiters just around the `$("div").append("<span>yyyyy</span>");` line.

Comment: Or, you can do it the hard way. `createElement('span');`, `createTextNode('yyyyy');` and so on and so forth; this doesn't require any less-than signs. However, the best way, the only way that you don't have to distinguish between HTML and XHTML environments, is to put all scripts in externally loaded .js files.